# iOS Bengali text parser for web URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, url

In my iOS app I am sending a Bengali text to a method where I need to convert the text into format to convert into web link because the website can only read this types. How can I convert my `NSString` into this format?

The url should look like:

> %E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%95/%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%95/%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%95/%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%95

url would be:

> www.xyz.com/translate/>%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%95/%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%95/%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%95/%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%95/>%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%95/%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%95/%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%95/%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%95-meaning-in-Bengali-English

In my code I did:

```
NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.xyz.com/translate/%@/%@-meaning-in-Bengali-English",txt,txt];    

NSString *ss =[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSLog(@"URL ::%@--%@",url,ss);
```

I am getting the direct URL only.

But it is not working in my way.

Any Solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, finally i parsed it using this method.

```
+(NSString *)encodeUrlString:(NSString *)string
{
    return CFBridgingRelease(
                             CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                     kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                     (__bridge CFStringRef)string,
                                                                     NULL,
                                                                     CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"),
                                                                     kCFStringEncodingUTF8)
                             );
}
```